# TypeError: 'LazyImporter' object is not callable

Tags: python, email, parsing

I have the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import email
from email import Parser;
import sys
import subprocess
import json

input = sys.stdin.read();

mail = Parser().parsestr(input); #Line 11
```

This resulted in the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./mail.py", line 11, in <module>
    mail = Parser().parsestr(input);
TypeError: 'LazyImporter' object is not callable
```

Does anyone have any suggestions regarding how this may be resolved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've imported the module `parser`, which of course isn't a function or class (callable). However, inside the module you'll find the class `Parser()`, so you want to change your code to

```
mail = Parser.Parser().parsestr(input)
```

or

```
from email.parser import Parser     # this is the class
mail = Parser().parsestr(input)
```